# Angular4/5: how to create folder, text file and write data into that file using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I need to create folder, text file and write data into that file in angular5 using typescript.This is to write errors in text file. Is it possible in angular?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, since in order to write a file in your computer (or a server) you need access to the file system. Javascript doesn't have a native file system module and neither the browser, so basically you can't do this from an Angular web application without deferring this task to a backend language in your server.

Comment: ok thanks for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Osman Cea said, this can not be done on client side. You can create file using [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL). But you can not save the file, since that would raise large security problems.

Since you want to record errors, you can post error to server and there store it to database or file system. That means you need some framework on the server side like PHP, ASP.NET Core ...

If you use Google analytics, another option (if you really want to avoid server framework which I do not recommend) is to use Google Analytics API. I once log client side errors to Google analytics with [API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events).

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Error',
  eventAction: window.location.href,
  eventLabel: your_error_object
});
```

Comment: @kamalav Does this answer you question or do you need additional explanation?

Comment: @kamalav Did you check what to do with answers to you questions? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). [Link2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).